# (loading images from gallery to app) emulator API 29 shows all pictures but when i run the mobile phone as an emulator no pictures are shown

Tags: java, android, gallery, deprecated

```
public class ImagesGallery {

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public static ArrayList<String> listOfImages (Context context){
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data;
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();
        String absolutePathOfImages;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};

        String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy+" DESC");

        if (cursor != null){
            column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                absolutePathOfImages = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

                listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImages);

            }
        }

        return listOfAllImages;
    }

}
```

**Activity** *mList (String-ArrayList) in Activity*

```
    private void loadImages() {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));

        mList = ImagesGallery.listOfImages(this); 
  

        galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(PhotoActivity.this, mList, new GalleryAdapter.PhotoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPhotoClick(String path) {
                Glide.with(PhotoActivity.this).load(path).into(image);
                imageData = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
        gallery_number.setText("Photos ("+mList.size()+")");

    }
```

**How can i make (MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA) situation compatible with android 10** I read the documentation but could not solve the problem,Any explanation about this situation would help me

Comment: You cannot use .DATA under Q. Instead use .RELATIVE_PATH.

Comment: `but when i run the mobile phone as an emulator`. Please explain how one runs a phone as an emulator.

Comment: mobile phone : xiaomi redmi 8 API-28

Comment: ??? You have explained nothing.

Comment: I just connect the phone to the computer with a usb cable, it appears as an emulator in Android studio

Comment: Sir, I'm confused, do you want to know how to connect your phone to android studio to use it as emulator? if that's your question, After connecting the phone to the computer with usb, you need to give permission as a developer from the settings of the phone.To do this, press ' the buil number' three or five times in the About phone section and then,a toast message will appear for you, as now you are a developer. also go to the developer option in settings, here allow usb debug